# Make an executable file from python project

Tags: python, tkinter, exe

I want to make a .exe file from my python project, I have made a GUI in tkinter. This project has multiple files and uses a variety of libraries.

I tried to use auto-py-to-exe but it gave a variety of errors concerning the use of tkinter, saying it can not find tkinter. I do not understand this error since tkinter is automatically installed with python? Are there better ways to use auto-py-to-exe or better programs to convert a hole project to .exe? I also tried pyinstaller, but when opening the program it immediately closes again. The program does run properly in pycharm.

The error is `I\output\main_init_.py", line 1, in <module> import tkinter ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'`

Comment: Please refer to this guide on how to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and read about [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Remember, we can't help you if we don't know what you've already tried / don't include any code.

Comment: I have already tried auto-to-py-exe and pyinstaller, but can not upload my hole project :)

Comment: Auto-py-to-exe just a visualized version of pyinstaller. It only adjusts parameters. Also, I used many times auto py to exe for various complex programs and always worked as expected. However there are some tricks to be known. So, if you don't provide reproducible code, your errors and what you've tried, we cannot help you.

Comment: Reproducible code is not your all project. Just get whatever causes problem and make its minimal runnable version so we can find the problem.

Comment: I do not understand what code I should upload, but the errors I get is that it says it can not find tkinter. After that I placed the whole tkinter folder in auto-py-to-exe but then it says can not find __future__, so I uploaded that file. After that it gave an error it could not find another specific file. After going on with this for a while I made no progress at all

Comment: But I am looking for a way to upload my old project structure to make it a .exe file

Comment: I have a main file that imports from another files that add multiple functions (consisting of multiple methods) to one big class. The main file runs this class (the tkinter GUI)

Comment: If some libraries looks missing you can put them into hidden imports to try it out. To see detailed errors you can use debug mode activated. Do you use one file or one folder mode?

Comment: "but the errors I get is that it says it can not find tkinter" - you could, at the very least, include the error message with your question.

Comment: I\output\main\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tkinter
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'

Comment: That is the error I got

Comment: @Elias Jriggles meant to put that into your question post. And it turns out my assumption of your error is probably the same one I run into. So take a look at my post and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I personally use CX-Freeze to compile my executables. I have probably used it over 100 or so updates of my tools and typically the problem I run into is either related to missing file that need to be identified in the setup.py file or the fact that when it compiles the Tkinter folder it uses a capital T instead of a lower case t so after I compiling an app I have to manually update the folder to be lowercase T.

Here is an example of the setup file.

As you can see below when compiling tkinter you need to ID the TK and TCL library folders in order for it to compile the listed DLL files properly.

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import os


base = "Win32GUI"

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Python381\tcl\tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Python381\tcl\tk8.6'


build_exe_options = {'packages': ['os',
                                  'json',
                                  'http',
                                  'email',
                                  'pyodbc',
                                  'openpyxl',
                                  'calendar',
                                  'threading',
                                  'datetime',

                                  'tkinter',
                                  'tkinter.ttk',
                                  'tkinter.messagebox'],
                     'excludes': ['PyQt5',
                                  'PIL',
                                  'numpy',
                                  'pandas'],  # 'urllib', # 'encodings', # 'numpy'

                     'include_files': [r'excel_temp.xlsx',
                                       r'opt_3_excel_temp.xlsx',
                                       r'tcoms_excel_temp.xlsx',
                                       r'main_config.json',
                                       r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Python381\DLLs\tcl86t.dll",
                                       r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Python381\DLLs\tk86t.dll"]}
    
setup(
    name='<GIT>',
    options={'build_exe': build_exe_options},
    version='0.57',
    description='<GIT - Global Inventory Tool!>',
    executables=[Executable(r'C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\Py381_GIT\MAIN.py', base=base)]
)
```

After you run the compiler you will often get an error that looks like this.

[image: Err]

The error `NoduleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'` is due to the odd behavior of the compiler giving the tkinter folder a Capital T like the below image in the `lib` folder.

[image: LIB]

[image: Tkinter]

In this case you would update the library to be a lowercase `t`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help, the error message I got looks the same as yours but my tkinter is with a lower case t.  Is it possible the problem can occur because of the file structure I follow? I have my .py files in a separate folder.

Comment: @elias Try using CX-Freeze. Otherwise it is hard to troubleshoot without a testable example in your question for us to review.

Comment: @elias what does your setup file look like. I suspect you did not include tkinter in your package list.

Answer (score 0):

Use this package :

```
python -m pip install auto-py-to-exe
```

Run this command :

```
auto-py-to-exe
```